# convert String to WebElement

Tags: java, webdriver

Is it possible to covert the string representation of a `WebElement` to a `WebElement`?

So if this is a class variable:

```
@FindBy(css = "select[id*='budTbl:0:j_id544']") 
WebElement roleList1;
```

And there's a string set to **roleList1**

Can the string be converted to the `WebElement` roleList1 so that it can be used in a statement such as

```
new Select(roleList1).getFirstSelectedOption().getText()
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you cannot convert String to a WebElement.

Instead, you could do something like,

```
if (myString.equals("roleList1"))
    new Select(roleList1).getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

No.
String to Webelement conversion is very tricky.
It needs dom and all knowledge

but if you just want to compare that same name element present on page or not then use below

```
public boolean methodname(String element_string_name)
{ 
val = false;
if (element_string_name.equals("string_name")) {
                element_name.isDisplayed();
                val = true;
}
return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert the `string` to `WebElement` but you can use the below one to do some action

```
string element = "("+MembersInfo_Content.ToString()+")[position()]["+i.ToString()+"]";
string memberInfo = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(element)).GetTextContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest tricks would be like:

Let suppose, something you need to modify in the xpath, in this case you can simply declare that xpath in the form of String like as shown below and then modify that xpath using .replace method:

```
 String xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'STR')]";
 xpath.replace("STR",str);
```

Then call this XPath using selenium, like,

```
driver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```