# Selenium String into WebElement for iteration

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have defined my web elements as following:

```
By elementABC= By.xpath("//div[@id='ABC']");
By elementDEF= By.xpath("//div[@id='DEF']");
```

Now I have a method that should take the the name as String (elementABC,elementDEF) and verify the presence of element. The String is being read from external file excel. The reason is so that I can iterate over multiple elements on a web page and just verify there presence.

```
public static boolean verifyElementPresent(String e) {
        boolean result= false;
        WebElement webObj=e; // this is where I'm facing trouble 
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(webObj);
        //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("elementDEF"));
        if (element.isDisplayed() ) {
            result=true;
        }
        else {
            result=false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

My problem is that I want to read a string and then be able to convert it into Web Element. The value of e being passed in my method is elementABC, elementDEF. And in next line I want to convert into WebElement.

```
WebElement webObj=e;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(webObj);
```

I came across a similar post on stackoverflow and noticed users have mentioned there is no good way to convert WebElement into String. But I still wanted to know if there is any other way of implementing this.

[convert String to WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921808/convert-string-to-webelement/51151472)

Comment: what does that string contains ?

Comment: String is being read from excel like below  elementABC, elementDEF

Comment: what does elementABC means!

Comment: By elementABC= By.xpath("//div[@id='ABC']"); OR  could be @FindBy(xpath="//div[@id='ABC']/")
WebElement elementABC;

Answer (score 0):

You should define `webObj` as **`By`** not **`WebElement`**.

To prevent the script from error when element not found, you still need to use **`try catch`**, like this:

```
public static boolean verifyElementPresent(String e) {
    boolean result= false;
    By webObj = By.xpath("//div[@id='" +e +"']");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(webObj);
    
    try {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            result=true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this approach for defining elements will not always work for me. 
By webObj = By.xpath("//div[@id='" +e +"']");       
Not all web elements can be defined with id. 

In some cases we use multiple combination like 
"//div[@id='mainNavigation']//a/span[text()='ABC']"

Comment: @stuart are the texts you are looking for unique? whether you can achieve it with this `By.xpath("//*[text()='" +e +"']");`?

Comment: Also in your code, what you have defined as webObj, i'm reading this particular element name as a string from excel. Hence my problem to convert this string into webelement.
By webObj = By.xpath("//div[@id='" +e +"']");
But thanks for your helpful suggestion.

Comment: Not in all cases. Please imagine a web page where you have 50 web elements on a homepage itself. Chances of identifying any web element on the basis of 'text' alone are slim.